# Caching assets in Angular application

Tags: angular, cache-control, angular12

What is the current best practise for caching assets (images, pdfs, other downloadable documents) in an Angular application?

Let's assume I have a PDF document named *agreement.pdf* that is linked on a page of the web application and to be downloaded by the user. I deployed the app with nginx setting header `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000` except for *index.html* that has no caching. Now I am changing the document, deploying and the user's browser that cached the document before must fetch the new version. Since angular doesn't hash assets, this will be a problem.

My current solution is to introduce cache-busting for assets. In my *angular.json* I specified:

```
...
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        ...
        "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/0/"
              }
        ],
        ...
```

I also added a pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Pipe({name: 'asset'})
export class AssetPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return assetUrl(value);
  }
}

export function assetUrl(assetName: string) {
  return "assets/" + environment.assetVersion + "/" + assetName;
}
```

which can be used in templates where an asset is referenced, e.g. `<img [src]="'agreement.pdf' | asset" />`. The function `assetUrl` can be used in component code. The *environment.ts* reads like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  assetVersion: '0'
};
```

Now, whenever an asset has changed, I modify two places: `environment.assetVersion` and the asset path in *angular.json*. Advantage: Only two places to modify for a new assets versions. Disadvantage: All assets must be refetched even if individual ones have not changed.

What's your solution to the problem?